# Is it possible to build an XML recursively without using any LINQ queries?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, reflection, linq-to-xml

1. I've asked a quesion earlier which can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13893662/building-xml-with-xelement-dynamically-through-recursion#comment19143146_13894023),
   and I was wondering whether the accepted answer's code can be done in normal programming *without* `Linq` query, any example will be very appreciated.
   Note that this is the way I've started to implement it, and had some problem through implementation.
2. I've managed to get private fields value through reflection without working with properties, is it problematic? Should I always take values through properties in reflection?

Code:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static XElement ToXml<T>(this T obj)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);

        return new XElement("Class",
                    new XElement(type.Name,
                        from pi in type.GetProperties()
                        where !pi.GetIndexParameters().Any()
                        let value = (dynamic)pi.GetValue(obj, null)
                        select pi.PropertyType.IsPrimitive || 
                               pi.PropertyType == typeof(string) ?
                                new XElement(pi.Name, value) : 
                                Extensions.ToXml(value)
                        )
                    );
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What kind of problems did you have with implementation? You have different opportunities to build xml - XmlWriter, XmlDocument, but what's wrong with LINQ?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky maybe he needs an earlier version of the .NET framework - linq is just from version 3 (3.5?)

Comment: @elyashiv well, then it's strange why he asked about `XElement` usage in previous question. I think there should be another problem

Comment: I really liked your answer and I think I've understand it completely but for general knowledge only I wondered whether I could do it my way.  In my Implementation there is no XmlWriter only using XElements to build the nested hierarchical xml. So I guess the answer is based somehow of using Xml writer also apart of using the c'tor of XElement?

Comment: Remember I'm all new to the XElement or LINQ stuff so maybe I've asked a stupid question, but that's all I know for now.

Comment: @JavaSa if you are using `System.Xml.Linq.XElement` then you are already using Linq. I think [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx) will be very helpful for you

Comment: Ok just for clarification I thought XElement is allowing me some kind of building an hierarchical XML without Linq queries, guess  I can't and the linq queries are inevitable part of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to use LINQ:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void ToXml<T>(this T obj, XmlWriter writer)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        writer.WriteStartElement("Class");
        writer.WriteStartElement(type.Name);

        foreach (PropertyInfo pi in type.GetProperties())
        {
            if (pi.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0)
                continue;

            var value = pi.GetValue(obj, null);            

            if (pi.PropertyType.IsPrimitive ||
                pi.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            {
                writer.WriteElementString(pi.Name, 
                                   (value == null) ? "" : value.ToString());
                continue;
            }

            if (value == null)
                continue;

            Extensions.ToXml((dynamic)value, writer);
        }

        writer.WriteEndElement();
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }   
}
```

Usage:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
using(var writer = XmlWriter.Create(sb))
    worker.ToXml(writer);

string xml = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: @JavaSa no problem, but see little update - I've added nulls handling (e.g. if Address or Name is null).